# How to Add Multiple Documents into one document in MongoDB?

Tags: database, mongodb

assume I have these three documents in a collection

```
{ "num" : 10, "count" : 1 }
{ "num" : 20, "count" : 2 }
{ "num" : 30, "count" : 3 }
```

Now I want to make one documents with sum of same fields(fields are same in all doc)

```
{ "num" : 60, "count" : 6 }
```

How to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write an aggregate query to do that.

1. Use `$group` with `$sum` to calculate the sum
2. Use projection's `$project` operator to remove the id key required by the $group operator

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $group: {
    _id: "",
    num: {
      $sum: "$num"
    },
    count: {
      $sum: "$count"
    }
  }
},
{
  $project: {
    _id: 0,
    num: "$num",
    count: "$count"
  }
})
```

[Playground link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hxNsVL9CbVe)